F10 keybinding of unknown origin (maybe Gnome?)
I am running Fedora 40 which I installed a few months ago. I noticed that F10 in my Emacs does not run the function that I have assigned to it in Emacs: in fact, Emacs does not see the F10 key any longer (and I am pretty sure that this started happening when I upgraded to Fedora 40: it was working fine in Fedora 38 - I skipped Fedora 39).
I can tell that Emacs does not see the key by using C-h C-k, the help function to describe a key, and pressing F10. Usually, the key is echoed in Emacs's echo area and the command bound to it is reported. In the F10 case, nothing is echoed in the echo area. Instead the File menu is dropped down.
That behavior seems to be somewhat general: both Firefox and Thunderbird exhibit the same behavior, which is another reason to conclude that the desktop environment is what's doing this. Not every application does this however: in gnome-terminal and xterm, F10 apparently just generates an escape sequence: ^[[21~.
I did gsettings list-recursively and found one entry using F10: that looked promising, so I set it to empty:
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface menubar-accel
'F10'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menubar-accel ''
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface menubar-accel
''

but that didn't do anything AFAICT (after various levels of restarting: restarting Emacs, logging out and back in, rebooting, shutting down and starting from scratch). As far as I know, all the graphical widget thingies (Settings, Tweaks, etc.) are using the Gsettings API underneath, so this should have found the culprit - but  no dice.
Since Emacs is built with libgtk-3.0, I also tried a GTK setting  as described in this answer but that also did not make any difference.
Although my main interest is to free up F10 from whoever its current master is and allow it to be passed to Emacs, I'd also be interested in any tips/hacks/methods you have come up with to deal with similar problems. Any ideas?
Version info:

OS: Fedora 40
Kernel: Linux 6.9.12-200.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Jul 27 15:56:15 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Gnome: 46.3
Emacs: bleeding-edge upstream, unreleased (31.0.50), but it also happens in the Emacs that comes with Fedora 40: GNU Emacs 29.4 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.42, cairo version 1.18.0) of 2024-07-16

If more information is needed, I'd be happy to supply it: please let me know.
UPDATE: in response to the comment by David G. below, xev does see F10 (and so do gnome-terminal and xterm as mentioned above, and of course whatever makes the File menu to drop down in the case of Emacs, Firefox and Thunderbird). The problem is not that it is not seen: the problem is that it is grabbed before I want it to be grabbed and I don't know what grabs it. That's what I'm trying to find out in the hope that I can convince that something to keep its hands off my F10 :)
In response to further comments by David G. (thanks for the responses and for keeping me honest!), I tried emacs -Q which starts Emacs without any initialization files (either site-init (site-start.el or user-init or early-init). But the GTK suggestion is intriguing. I built an Emacs without a toolkit at all and it behaves as expected wrt to F10: the key is visible and I can bind it to a command. I then found this section in the GTK documentation: it's about GTK4 and I cannot find the equivalent in the GTK3 documentation, but I'm assuming that the behavior is the same in the two versions. I'm no GTK programmer, so I don't know how to turn this behavior off yet, but it seems clear that David G. was right when he fingered the GTK interface in Emacs as the culprit.

I think emacs uses a two-stage input handling process, and C-h C-k only does the second.  I can't remember details of the first stage.   I would recommend trying a basic debugging program, like xev, to see if it receives F10.  This will let you determine if the problem is in emacs or something external to it.

C-h k uses the same primitive read-key-sequence as the REPL does, so no, that's not correct. It also does something more: it reports the raw key sequence, before any translation keymaps. In the case of F10, it reports nothing because it doesn't see it. It has no such problem with F9 or F11 or any other function key: it can see all of them fine. xev can see F10, but xev is at a much lower level: it gets its hands on it before the desktop environment.

There are other keys that are intercepted by the DE and never seen by Emacs, e.g. Alt-F2: that's not the strange thing - gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog says <Alt>F2, so it is clear that it is intercepted. The strange thing is that F10 no longer appears in gsettings but it still drops down the File menu (and not only in Emacs).

I suspect you will find that <Alt>F2 is also intercepted before xev.  I suspect F10 is being intercepted inside emacs, probably in the GTK interface, possibly in site lisp.

You are right that <Alt>F2 is intercepted before xev: I was wrong that xev gets its hands on it early. OTOH, starting Emacs with emacs -Q i.e. no site-init or user-init file still shows the problem, so if the problem is in Emacs, it is in its core. I've updated the question with some possible ways forward - e.g. building Emacs without GTK. I'll update again after I get some sleep. Thanks!

@DavidG. I think you are right about GTK - see my updates in the question. I still don't know how to turn off this behavior (it will probably require a patch to the C code of Emacs), but if you wish to make your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

I think emacs uses a two-stage input handling process (plus another at the front if you count GTK), and C-h k only does the last. I can't remember details of the earlier stage (but I think it was about certain key remappings).
I would recommend trying a basic debugging program, like xev, to see if it   receives F10. This will let you determine if the problem is in emacs or something external to it.
I suspect you will find that most special/intercepted keys (like <Alt>F2) are also intercepted before xev.
I suspect F10 is being intercepted inside emacs, probably in the GTK interface, possibly in site lisp, and possibly in the elisp configurations and interconnections of the GTK interface.  (The last is to say: maybe you should look for menu-bar and F10 references in any GTK specific elisp files.)

I don't believe that the first paragraph is correct (for the reasons explained in my comment), but I am convinced at this point that an Emacs built with GTK support exhibits the problem described in the question, whereas one without GTK support does not.
